# Keyboard Shortcut for 'New Swatch' in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, automation, shortcuts

Does a keyboard shortcut for creating a New Swatch in the Colour Palette window in Illustrator exist? I've been assembling over hundreds of new swatches today, and it has been especially tedious to click through the application...

Any tricks or tips that you guys use to accelerate this process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no default shortcut, but you can make your own shortcut by going to:

`Edit -> Keyboard Shortcuts` (<kbd>Alt + Shift + Ctrl + K</kbd>)

Then, under the (second) dropdown menu select `Menu Commands` and then navigate to
`Other Panel -> New Swatch`. There you can assign your custom keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Please note: I used CS5 for this, so the exact details may be different for other version. But I hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 2):

See if this works for you:

1. Eyedropper your new color.
2. There's a "new swatch" button at the
   bottom of the Swatches palette.
   Click that, type the new name.
   OR
3. Drag the color onto the Swatches
   palette. The RGB or CYMK
   values are the new name.

Are either of those faster?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't one, but there is the ability to create swatch libraries and import them into new documents for easy re-use. @Lauren's suggestion of dragging is marginally faster than clicking the button or using the palette menu.